# How to Quit GtkApplication on window focus-out-event?

Tags: c, gtk3

This is an example of widget "focus-out-event" in gtk3. My goal is to exit the window whenever it loses focus by clicking outside the window. But having problem with combobox (child) widget. Whenever I click on the combobox, the window loses focus and closes. But if I click on a scale widget, no problem. This is the script--

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example Changer3.c`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` 

gboolean quit_function (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event, gpointer   user_data)
{
    GApplication *app=g_application_get_default();
    g_application_quit(app);
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
    //create Window 
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *center_vbox;
    GtkWidget *combobox;
    GtkWidget *scale;

    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_decorated (GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW(window), 230, 100);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 230, 100);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW(window), "config");
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_keep_above (GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);

    center_vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 2);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), center_vbox);
    combobox = gtk_combo_box_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (center_vbox), combobox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    scale = gtk_scale_new_with_range(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0, 50, 1);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (center_vbox), scale, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    //focus-out-event event to auto hide window
    gtk_widget_set_events (window, GDK_FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(window), "focus-out-event", G_CALLBACK(quit_function), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
  char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

I want the window so that when I click on any child widget(combobox/scale) it doesn't close. But if i click on outside the window application window should quit.

Comment: The `linux`, `debian`, and `ubuntu` tags should only be used when doing distro-specific development, not merely because that's what your OS is. See the tag text: "Use this tag only if your question relates to development on Debian using operating system API's or Debian-specific features, or to creating packages in the deb format." That's why I removed them earlier.

Comment: Instead of telling what you want it to do, maybe tell us what you are trying to achieve. This seems like a classical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).